# Android ARCGIS Shape file labeling polylines

Tags: android, label, arcgis, shapefile, polyline

I have my ARCGIS android app displaying a polyline shapefile file  - a roading network in this case.

The shape file has a field  that contains the name of the road "ROAD_NAME' - the question i have is how do i create a layer to have the road name automatically displayed?

cheers

B

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to display labels on the map.
By my experiment, there are 2 ways. I realized it.One way is that draw those labels programmatically on the map. but it needs a lot of effort. I did it, it is not pretty. I think so.

```
public class LabelLayer extends GraphicsLayer {
...
 private void showLabel(final FeatureLayer fly, final QueryParameters query,final String labelField) {
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        fly.getFeatureTable().queryFeatures(query, new CallbackListener<FeatureResult>() {
         @Override
         public void onCallback(FeatureResult objects) {
           Iterator<Object> fet=objects.iterator();
              while (fet.hasNext()){
                Feature f=(Feature) fet.next();
                Geometry geom= f.getGeometry();
                Point    p=null;
                        switch (geom.getType()){
                            case POINT:p=(Point)geom;break;
                            case POLYLINE: Polyline polyline=(Polyline)geom;break;
                            case POLYGON:  p= GeometryEngine.getLabelPointForPolygon((Polygon)geom,mapView.getSpatialReference());break;
                            default:break;

                        }
               txtSymbol.setFontWeight(FontWeight.BOLD);
               txtSymbol.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
               txtSymbol.setText(f.getAttributeValue(labelField).toString());
                        Graphic gr = new Graphic(p, txtSymbol);
                        LabelLayer.this.addGraphic(gr);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();


}
...
}
```

this class should be implemented in onDraw() method.
the second is that use the tpk of ArcGIS.
I think it would be better much.

Comment: can you share me how to get shapefile parameters?